# Blank View Controller When Dismissing Interstitial Flurry Ad On iOS 5/5.1

Tags: ios, ios5, ads, flurry

I implemented FlurryAds on my iOS app, and created an Interstitial/Full-screen ad. Requesting and showing the ad works fine, but after I close the ad, all of my ViewController elements that were inside the .xib file become invisible. I know they are still there because if I tap on the screen the buttons that were there still respond.

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Edit: Forgot to post more information, I'm using XCode 4.5.2, my project is using ARC, no Storyboard, and the Flurry SDK is 4.0.6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I finally figured out the problem and it was because of my misunderstanding how view controllers work.

All my view controllers inherited from a custom view controller, which had a full background image being added on viewDidLoad, which then faded out. All I had to do was separate adding the full background image on viewDidLoad, but having the fade out animation inside the viewDidAppear method.

Answer (score 0):

This bug arises when you enter the viewController using 
**"`[self presentModalViewController: viewController animated:YES]`"**

Try to use this
**"`[self.navigationController pushViewController: viewController animated:YES]`"**

Hope this will help you 
:)

Comment: did you change the appdelegate too?